# openai whisper training IndexError: Invalid key: 0 is out of bounds for size 0

Tags: python-3.x, openai-whisper

i'm trying to train whisper with my custom wav file.

However, i keep getting error message as below :

IndexError: Invalid key: 0 is out of bounds for size 0

For the record, i'm using googlecolab for this project.

And this is my minimum proof of concept, so i'm using just one wav file trying

go through whole process of language training with openai whisper.

- wav file, txt file, csv files are in designated directory of google drive.

Which part of this code should be corrected?

```
import pandas as pd
from datasets import Dataset, Audio
from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor, WhisperTokenizer, WhisperProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer
import torch
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Union
import evaluate
import soundfile as sf
from scipy.signal import resample

# Google 드라이브 마운트
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Google 드라이브 내의 데이터셋 경로 지정 (수정 필요)
train_csv_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/sully/wav/cff.csv'
test_csv_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/sully/wav/test.csv'

# 데이터셋 로드
train_df = pd.read_csv(train_csv_path)
test_df = pd.read_csv(test_csv_path)

# 열 이름 변경
train_df.columns = ["audio", "sentence"]
test_df.columns = ["audio", "sentence"]

# Dataset 객체로 변환
train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(train_df)
test_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(test_df)

# Audio 데이터타입으로 캐스팅
train_dataset = train_dataset.cast_column("audio", Audio(sampling_rate=16000))
test_dataset = test_dataset.cast_column("audio", Audio(sampling_rate=16000))

# 특성 추출기, 토크나이저 및 프로세서 로드
feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-base")
tokenizer = WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-base", language="English", task="transcribe")
processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-base", language="English", task="transcribe")

# 데이터 전처리 함수
def prepare_dataset(examples):
    audio = examples["audio"]
    examples["input_features"] = feature_extractor(audio["array"], sampling_rate=16000).input_features
    del examples["audio"]
    examples["labels"] = tokenizer(examples["sentence"]).input_ids

# 데이터셋에 함수 적용
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(prepare_dataset, num_proc=1)
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(prepare_dataset, num_proc=1)

# 데이터 콜레이터 정의
@dataclass
class DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding:
    processor: Any
    def __call__(self, features: List[Dict[str, Union[List[int], torch.Tensor]]]) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        input_features = [{"input_features": feature["input_features"]} for feature in features]
        batch = self.processor.feature_extractor.pad(input_features, return_tensors="pt")
        label_features = [{"input_ids": feature["labels"]} for feature in features]
        labels_batch = self.processor.tokenizer.pad(label_features, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
        labels = labels_batch["input_ids"].masked_fill(labels_batch["attention_mask"].ne(1), -100)
        if (labels[:, 0] == self.processor.tokenizer.bos_token_id).all():
            labels = labels[:, 1:]
        batch["labels"] = labels
        return batch

# 데이터 콜레이터 초기화
data_collator = DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding(processor=processor)

# 평가 지표 로드
metric = evaluate.load("wer")

# 평가 지표 계산 함수
def compute_metrics(pred):
    pred_ids = pred.predictions
    label_ids = pred.label_ids
    label_ids[label_ids == -100] = tokenizer.pad_token_id
    pred_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    label_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(label_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    wer = metric.compute(predictions=pred_str, references=label_str)
    return {"wer": wer}

# 사전 훈련된 체크포인트 로드
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-base")

# 훈련 인자 정의
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='/content/drive/My Drive/sully/checkpoint',  # Google 드라이브 내 모델 저장 경로
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    evaluation_strategy="no",
    save_steps=10,
    logging_steps=1,
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    warmup_steps=0,
    weight_decay=0.0,
    report_to="none",
    load_best_model_at_end=False,
    max_steps=10,
    push_to_hub=False
)

# 트레이너 초기화
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset.select([0]),  # 한 개의 데이터만 사용
    eval_dataset=None,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=None,
    tokenizer=processor.tokenizer,
)

# 훈련 시작
trainer.train()

# 모델과 프로세서 저장 (필요한 경우)
model_save_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/sully/checkpoint'
processor_save_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/sully/checkpoint'
model.save_pretrained(model_save_path)
processor.save_pretrained(processor_save_path)
  ``

and below is detail of error message.

> Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True).
Map: 100%
1/1 [00:00<00:00, 7.14 examples/s]
Map: 100%
1/1 [00:02<00:00, 2.88s/ examples]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a24d1a6ecbf8> in <cell line: 116>()
    114 
    115 # 훈련 시작
--> 116 trainer.train()
    117 
    118 # 모델과 프로세서 저장 (필요한 경우)

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1535                 hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   1536         else:
-> 1537             return inner_training_loop(
   1538                 args=args,
   1539                 resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1819 
   1820             step = -1
-> 1821             for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
   1822                 total_batched_samples += 1
   1823 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/accelerate/data_loader.py in __iter__(self)
    446         # We iterate one batch ahead to check when we are at the end
    447         try:
--> 448             current_batch = next(dataloader_iter)
    449         except StopIteration:
    450             yield

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    628                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    629                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 630             data = self._next_data()
    631             self._num_yielded += 1
    632             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    672     def _next_data(self):
    673         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 674         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    675         if self._pin_memory:
    676             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     47         if self.auto_collation:
     48             if hasattr(self.dataset, "__getitems__") and self.dataset.__getitems__:
---> 49                 data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     50             else:
     51                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in __getitems__(self, keys)
   2802     def __getitems__(self, keys: List) -> List:
   2803         """Can be used to get a batch using a list of integers indices."""
-> 2804         batch = self.__getitem__(keys)
   2805         n_examples = len(batch[next(iter(batch))])
   2806         return [{col: array[i] for col, array in batch.items()} for i in range(n_examples)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798     def __getitem__(self, key):  # noqa: F811
   2799         """Can be used to index columns (by string names) or rows (by integer index or iterable of indices or bools)."""
-> 2800         return self._getitem(key)
   2801 
   2802     def __getitems__(self, keys: List) -> List:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in _getitem(self, key, **kwargs)
   2782         format_kwargs = format_kwargs if format_kwargs is not None else {}
   2783         formatter = get_formatter(format_type, features=self._info.features, **format_kwargs)
-> 2784         pa_subtable = query_table(self._data, key, indices=self._indices if self._indices is not None else None)
   2785         formatted_output = format_table(
   2786             pa_subtable, key, formatter=formatter, format_columns=format_columns, output_all_columns=output_all_columns

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py in query_table(table, key, indices)
    581     else:
    582         size = indices.num_rows if indices is not None else table.num_rows
--> 583         _check_valid_index_key(key, size)
    584     # Query the main table
    585     if indices is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py in _check_valid_index_key(key, size)
    534     elif isinstance(key, Iterable):
    535         if len(key) > 0:
--> 536             _check_valid_index_key(int(max(key)), size=size)
    537             _check_valid_index_key(int(min(key)), size=size)
    538     else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py in _check_valid_index_key(key, size)
    524     if isinstance(key, int):
    525         if (key < 0 and key + size < 0) or (key >= size):
--> 526             raise IndexError(f"Invalid key: {key} is out of bounds for size {size}")
    527         return
    528     elif isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: Invalid key: 0 is out of bounds for size 0
```